# hg clone run by Bamboo gives different result from command line

Tags: mercurial, bamboo, hg

A Bamboo "Source Code Checkout" task on a linked mercurial repo gives a different result than hg clone run on the command line: Both have a different subset of all named branches checked out.

How can I make Bamboo checkout give an identical result to command line checkout?

I apologize for the brevity. I initially gave much more detail, but a bot told me to

> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Happy to follow up with whatever helps.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The key part of that community suggestion, which is the result of flags raised by community members and only DELIVERED by the bot, is that you asked several questions in your previous version. We need more detail, but we need one question, because that is how this site works.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. In my opinion the indeed multiple questions were inseparably related and formed a single complex. Anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither Bamboo nor mercurial did anything *wrong*. Bamboo intrinsically performs an `hg init` on the cache dir, followed by an `hg pull --rev REV`. The --rev will only pull ancestors of REV.

It so happens that there are branches in the repo that have never been merged into the one that's built. Those branches' changesets are no ancestors of REV and thus omitted by Bamboo's pull. This explains the discrepancy to an `hg clone` or an `hg pull` without --rev both of which will fetch *all* changesets.

I don't see a way to configure Bamboo's mercurial plugin so that it pulls without --rev. Also while I can perform a subsequent pull on the cached repo to obtain the missing branches, there seems to be no way to reset the revision numbers to match those of a pull without --rev as the changesets from the first pull will keep their revision numbers.

So we ended up dropping the use of the integer revision number, which is the sensible thing to do with a DVCS anyway whenever you work not strictly local to a single repo.